# How write a function to see if an array is prime-sparse without using built in functions in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a function to see if an array is prime-sparce in Java.

> An array is defined to be prime-sparse if no prime-valued elements are
>   adjacent to one another.
>
> Recall that a prime number is a positive integer whose only factors
>   are 1 and itself. For example:
>
> - The array `{6, 11, 13, 28, 5, 6}` is not prime-sparse because the primes 11 and 13 are next to one another.
> - The array `{6, 11, 88, 13, 28, 5, 6, 17}` is prime sparse because the    11 and 13 are separated by a non-prime (88).
> - If the array has no    primes, then it is prime-sparse by definition.
>
> Write a function named `isPrimeSparse` that returns 1 if its array
>   argument is prime-sparse, otherwise it returns 0.

I've tried the code below, but it's not working as I wanted.

```
public int isPrimeSparse(int [] a){
    for (int i=1; i<a.length; ++i)
        if (isPrimeSparse(a[i]) && isPrimeSparse(a[i-1]))
            return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Can anybody help me figuring out what is going on?

Comment: how i can do that without built in functions in java ,actually the problem is how to find the prime numbers in the array ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question, which does not include the required summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, nor a description of the difficulty encountered in solving it.

Comment: Why the C++ tag spam? I've edited the question and have deleted the irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 3):

Hint 1: you need to write (or use) a method that tests if a number is prime.

Hint 2: how do you test if a number is prime?  For a simple way, just look at the definition of a prime number.

Hint 3: a prime sparse array does not have two (or more) primes in a row.